# How to select the checkboxes .length and output it in an html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For an exercise, I would like to know how many checkboxes are checked and output the .length of These with a button in an HTML Element.

This is as far as I got...

**Code:**

```js
/*Anzahl*/
function cname() {
  var canzahl = document.getElementsByClassName('.classes').options;
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < canzahl.length; i++) {
    if (canzahl[i].selected)
      count++;
  }
  document.getElementById('mklassen').innerHTML = count;
}
/*Ausgabe*/
function ausgabe() {
  document.getElementById('Ausgabe').innerHTML =
    cname();
};
```

```css
/*Checkbox*/
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:not(checked)+label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:checked+label:before {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="cclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="cclass">BI15b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="bclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="bclass">BI16b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="dclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="dclass">BI17b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="eclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="eclass">BI18b</label>


<input id="Ausgabe" class="ausgabe" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="ausgabe();">
<!--Names-->
<p>Markierte Klassen:</p>
<p id="mklaasen"></p>
```

For your information I have seen answers on stackoverflow to this question already. Sadly These were either done with jQuery or just did not work for me.

Comment: Here is a 'best practices' approach to the same problem https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/q5xnrL07/23/

Answer (score 3):

You can find all checked checkboxes in the page using this code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

If you want to output the length in an html element:

```
myElement.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes on your part:

On checkboxes you are looking for the `.checked` state

Also, I didn't know why there was the `.options` on your selector. So removing it helped.

Finally, when your try to put count in the innerHtml. The id's didn't match.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
/*Anzahl*/
function cname() {
  var canzahl = document.getElementsByClassName('classes');
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < canzahl.length; i++) {
    if (canzahl[i].checked)
      count++;
  }
  console.log(count);
  document.getElementById('mklaasen').innerHTML = count;
}
/*Ausgabe*/
function ausgabe() {
  document.getElementById('Ausgabe').innerHTML =
    cname();
};
```

```css
/*Checkbox*/
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:not(checked)+label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:checked+label:before {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="cclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="cclass">BI15b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="bclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="bclass">BI16b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="dclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="dclass">BI17b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="eclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="eclass">BI18b</label>


<input id="Ausgabe" class="ausgabe" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="ausgabe();">
<!--Names-->
<p>Markierte Klassen:</p>
<p id="mklaasen"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found 3 issues in your code.

- `getElementsByClassName` should expect `classes` not `.classes`
- There shouldn't be any options property in `getElementsByClassName` method
- You misspelled id name which causes null innerHTML.

```js
/*Anzahl*/
function cname() {
  var canzahl = document.getElementsByClassName('classes');
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < canzahl.length; i++) {
    if (canzahl[i].checked)
      count++;
  }
  document.getElementById('mklaasen').innerHTML = count;
}
/*Ausgabe*/
function ausgabe() {
  document.getElementById('Ausgabe').innerHTML =
    cname();
};
```

```css
/*Checkbox*/
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:not(checked)+label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*Checkbox*/
.classes:checked+label:before {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="cclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="cclass">BI15b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="bclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="bclass">BI16b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="dclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="dclass">BI17b</label>
<input class="classes" type="checkbox" value="text" id="eclass" name="class">
<label class="class" for="eclass">BI18b</label>


<input id="Ausgabe" class="ausgabe" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="ausgabe();">
<!--Names-->
<p>Markierte Klassen:</p>
<p id="mklaasen"></p>
```